# Netbeans generating .jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

When I clean and build, Netbeans generates a .jar file for my Java project, and it uses a "lib" folder which has all of my external Jar files that I use. Can I somehow tell Netbeans to package these Jar files into the .jar it makes? So that I can run my project as a stand-alone .jar file?

I am using Netbeans 7.1.1 on Mac OSX

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212913/netbeans-deploying-all-in-one-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, the long answer is complicated.

Firstly, Java does not support embedded Jars (ie, you cann't simply add the depended Jars into the main Jar).

Secondly, uncompressing all the Jars and merging them into one will overwrite any resources/classes that share the same path/name.  This may not be an issue in small projects but is a major issue in large ones (we have this problem with the project I'm working on at work).

One solution is to use something like [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), which basically uses it's own boot class loader to all you to reference Jars inbedded within a single Jar.

I've had issues with this when using our own custom classloader, but otherwise it seems to work well.

It includes Ant support, so you can include it in your projects Ant build script, if you not using Maven, otherwise, you'll need to devise your own build process

Comment: so how does a .jar file know where to get the correct drivers from? is a "lib" folder mandatory outside of a .jar file?

Comment: There is a class-path property inside the manifest file of the main jar which the class loader uses to find dependent class. Check out [Working with Manifest Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

There is no options in netbeans to do that.

There are some other options that a quick search would help, but requires manual intervention.