# How can I merge all libraries into the main jar file?

Tags: java, jar

When I build the project in NetBeans it shows in lib folder these libraries

```
client-combined-3.141.59.jar
client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar
commons-exec-1.3.jar
cryptolens.jar
guava-25.0-jre.jar
okhttp-3.11.0.jar
okio-1.14.0.jar
```

so whenever I want to move the project I need to copy them with it!
How can I merge them into the main jar application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building a fat jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)

Comment: Or this: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: The problem in this particular case is that your current project might not be a Maven one. In this case, you can add a custom target to your Ant build file. That's covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212913/netbeans-deploying-all-in-one-jar)
If I were using Netbeans now, I'd probably always choose a Maven build. Although I liked Ant, I'm afraid it was always rendered write-only (much like a wizard GUI builder) by Netbeans.

Comment: It might be safer to just start again and move your source over into a new Maven project and use Shade.

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple.

1. Just rename the .jar file (the main jar) to .zip file (if you use
   windows 7 you can't do this you need to use git terminal or cmd to do that)
2. Copy lib folder and open .zip file (main jar)
3. Paste it
4. Rename the main jar to name.jar file