# Create on single .JAR with no lib folder

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NetBeans - deploying all in one jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212913/netbeans-deploying-all-in-one-jar)

I am using netbeans to develop a project.  My project also depends on the javaMail files which I added using Netbeans libraries.  When I build the project I get a dist folder under which is my jar file and a lib folder.  I want to distribute the project simply to my users and want to some how wrap the lib contents into the project jar file.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this using Netbeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few posts on this topic:

- [Put external libraries to the jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034180/put-external-library-to-the-jar) (NetBeans specific)
- [Netbeans - deploying all in one jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212913/netbeans-deploying-all-in-one-jar) (NetBeans specific)
- [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)
- [Java: Easiest way to merge a release into one jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/java-easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file)

And others specific to other build environments and IDEs