# How to pack APIs into JARs

Tags: java, api, jar

I have a GUI program that returns CPU values, this requires a external API. I have the JAR made, but the program will not return the CPU unless I run the program within netbeans IDE. My question is how can I pack APIs into a JAR file.

```
private class getCpu extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
                Cpu cpu = new Cpu();
                CpuPerc perc = sigar.getCpuPerc();

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.###");
                //df.format(100-(perc.getIdle()*100));
                cpuLabel.setText("CPU : "+df.format(100-(perc.getIdle()*100))+"%");

                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e2){}
                }catch(SigarException e1){}
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Presumably that API is defined and implemented in some library JAR.  You need to ensure that JAR is on the classpath when you run your program.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth please explain this to me

Comment: I think you want to achieve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034180/put-external-library-to-the-jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using sigar's API you must add the log4j.jar and sigar.jar to your class-path. But also you need to add sigar-amd64-winnt.dll, sigar-x86-winnt.dll, and sigar-x86-winnt.lib to the final folder with the final build otherwise Sigar will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your program isn't working because you have no "*external API*"  in your `classpath` when you run the program from command line (and you got `ClassDefNotFoundException`)

To solve this problem you can do one of:

- add the *external API* jar to classpath:
  `java -cp externalAPI.jar -jar jourProgram.jar`
- pack all necessary classes into your jar. There is a good `maven plugin` it can take all your dependencies and pack into a single jar file - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: The program opens when I execute from command line, but still it doesn't return the cpu unless I run it inside of NetBeans. Any ideas?

Comment: Any exceptions or error messages?
Can you paste a command you are using to lunch the program from command-line?

Comment: No errors what-so-ever. I cd to the folder that has the jar then : java -jar GuiCpu.jar

Comment: But you do not add *the external API* to your classpath like: `-cp external.jar` There is no error because you probably "swallow" the exception. Paste the code responsible for receiving cpu load.

Comment: Ok I added the code, but on a side note the code works fine within netbeans, but when I build the jar in netbeans it will not work outside of netbeans. (it will open, but not get the cpu percentage)

Comment: So now I can see that you swallow all exceptions (there are empty `catch` statements - add `e.printStarcktrace()` in every catch block and you will see the cause of your problem). **Never swallow `Exception` because you will never know whats is wrong since no error will be reported.**

You are using `Sigar API` but you forgot to add it to your classpath like this `-cp sigar.jar`

Comment: Ok sorry I figured out what I was doing wrong, thanks for your help. I'm posting an answer now to my question.