# NetBeans and One-Jar Creation for Stand alone application

Tags: swing, netbeans, jar, launch4j, onejar

Please help me out,I have developed the simple application with two external jar files.While clean and build,it's creating a jar file for the application and the library folder in dist directory. When I try to execute as a jar,it's executing perfectly

But When I converted the jar into exe file using launch4j,after conversion,the execution is reporting NoClassDefFoundError.

I Hope, One-Jar is a solution for ma problem, But How to do One-Jar in Netbeans IDE or how to wrap all the dependency libraries with the application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch4J - how to attach dependent jars to generated exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917960/launch4j-how-to-attach-dependent-jars-to-generated-exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are yet answers to this question here:

- [NetBeans - deploying all in one jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212913/netbeans-deploying-all-in-one-jar)
- [Put external library to the JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034180/put-external-library-to-the-jar)

Comment: The Blog link, Which I found in the Stack overflow, helped me to sort out my problem :) Thank U All