# How to use internal libraries / references in a JAR from Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm in the process of creating a JAR file using Netbeans. I am coming across a problem where I can not reference images or libraries without the `/lib` folder present with the JAR and my images in the JAR's current working directory. I need this JAR to be self contained and so when I build it I make sure that my library file and associated images are all within the JAR file itself. However my manifest file seems to be pointing to outside of the JAR as do any references associated with my JAR file. Is there a way within Netbeans to change these options when building?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to put several files inside the Jar file, but it didn't crossed my mind to do so with the libraries.

Try to see this link: https://www.google.pt/#q=JAVA+put+libraries+inside+JAR.

As far I can see in a small rechearch, is possible using external tools, or simply using ant.
Check this link as well (as shown in the previous link I gave you): [Put external library to the JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034180/put-external-library-to-the-jar)

Google is a powerfull tool, use it more often.

I hope I could help.