# Error when i try to make executable file from .jar file

Tags: java, netbeans

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout

```
at ApplicationPackage.StartPage.initComponents(StartPage.java:300)
at ApplicationPackage.StartPage.<init>(StartPage.java:57)
at ApplicationPackage.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

My code:

try {

```
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Eroare la aplicarea stilului ferestrei", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    StartPage frame = new StartPage();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

How to solve this ?

Update: I solve this error.
But now a have another question. How I can create a jar file with is in dependencies with a database ? My app write and read from a H2 database file.

Comment: You need to include the classes you use.

Comment: where and how ? How can I include the IDE's AbsoluteLayout class in my JAR?

Comment: In the JAR.  That depends on how you're making the JAR.

Comment: Check imports and make sure that you have included the required jar files. Make sure that supporting jars are included while creating executable.

Comment: i work in Netbeans, after clean and biuld project i get the jar file. I so need to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` generally means the class isn't found on the classpath.

Here's some simple steps and things to look for (Using Netbeans).

- When you add the library take these steps

  1. Right click on the [Library] node in the project from the [Projects] explorer tab.
  2. Select [Add Library]. AbsoluteLayout should be the first one.
- Build you project. All the libraries should be exported to the [lib] folder, if you haven't changed any default build settings. Then you need to check a couple things:

  1. Check to make sure the library is actually there. Go to the [Files] tab (if it's not open, go to [Window]->[Files]) and make sure the library is in the [libs] dir:

     [image]
  2. Then check to make sure the library is on the classpath. Check the `MANIFIEST.MF`.

     [image]

     You should see the `libs\AbsuluteLayout.jar` on the classapth

     > Manifest-Version: 1.0
     >    Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
     >    Created-By: 1.8.0_20-b26 (Oracle Corporation)
     >    Class-Path: lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar
     >    X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
     >    Main-Class: addjardemo.AddJarDemo

If all this is correct, what this means is that when you run your jar, the jar should be on the same level as the [lib] directory, as the application is dependent on that jar in that exact location (relative to the calling jar). Note: this is not the only way though. For more information, I'd do some research on "classpath"

If you want all the classes included into *your* jar, you will need to build an "Uber Jar". Not sure how to do this with Netbeans settings (if its even possible), but you can search for similar topics, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034180/put-external-library-to-the-jar)

Comment: thanks, I solve this error.
But now a have another question. How I can create a jar file with is in dependencies with a database ? My app write and read from a H2 database file.

Comment: Do you have the H2 jar? Just do the same thing as with the AbsolutLayout jar, but instead when you right click on the Library node, select Add Jar.

Comment: What do you expect me to do with that image?

Comment: this is my class to conect http://i.imgur.com/vjfiBAu.png

this is the frame to be opened http://i.imgur.com/6vBRnlL.png

this is the error http://i.imgur.com/KVv9BbB.png

after building I can't acces the databse

Comment: You really need to learn how to debug NullPointerExceptions. Read [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). No one can help you debug this will images and no code. Sorry. If you want to share any code, POST the CODE, not images of exception. And copy and paste the stack trace

Comment: but why in netbeans all works fine, and after build and clean doesn't work

Comment: What is line 27 that is throwing the exception? Look there

Comment: it seems I solved the problem with the exceptions from command line, but after I make the .exe with LaunchJ again I obtain these exceptions

Answer (score 0):

this is my function to get data from db

```
 public Vector getData(String query)throws Exception
    {
        Vector<Vector<String>> dataVector = new Vector<>();

        try (Connection myConnection = ConectDataBase.ConectToBD()) {
            PreparedStatement pst = myConnection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                Vector<String> films = new Vector<>();
                films.add(rs.getString(1)); 
                films.add(rs.getString(2)); 
                films.add(rs.getString(3)); 
                films.add(rs.getString(4)); 
                films.add(rs.getString(5));
                films.add(rs.getString(6));
                films.add(rs.getString(7));
                films.add(rs.getString(8));
                films.add(rs.getString(9));
                dataVector.add(films);
            }
        }
        return dataVector;
    }
```

this is in the frame which contains the extracdet data

```
public ListOfFilms() throws Exception {

        // extragerea datelor din baza de date
        PopulateDataTable dbengine = new PopulateDataTable();
        data = dbengine.getData("SELECT * FROM DataStructure ORDER BY id DESC");
        initComponents();
```

}

this is my class to connect to db

```
public class ConectDataBase {

Connection myConnection;

public static Connection ConectToBD(){

    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~//RatedMovies", "", "");

        return myConnection;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
        return null;
    }                     
}
```

}