# Creating a bundle jar for javafx application

Tags: deployment, ant, javafx, bundle, jar-with-dependencies

I am trying to bundle all libraries to one jar for my JavaFX application using ANT. I found the following [Creating a bundle jar with ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821803/creating-a-bundle-jar-with-ant) but could not get it to work. Adding the library *.jar files can be done in `<fx:jar>` by adding `<fileset>`:

```
<fileset dir="build" includes="libs/*.jar"></fileset>
```

The `build` directory contains:

```
build
  |-- classes (compiled classes)
  |-- libs (external libraries)
  |-- src (sources)
```

The generated jar now contains the `libs` directory with all the libraries.

How can I tell the generated jar that is should look into the `libs` directory inside the jar and not outside it?

Thanks!

Comment: See: [Classpath including JAR within a JAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you jewesea!

I could not make any of those libraries work with JavaFX. But I found this: https://community.oracle.com/message/10266894

so after `<fx:jar>` i unpack and repack all libraries and it works.

```
<target name="do-deploy-bundle" depends="init-properties, do-deploy-dist">
    <property name="tmp.file" value="temp_final.jar"/>

    <delete file="${dist.dir}/${app.jar}" />
    <delete dir="${bundle-dist.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${bundle-dist.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${bundle-dist.dir}/${tmp.file}" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${dist.dir}/libs" includes="*.jar" />

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${app.vendor}"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${app.name}"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${app.version}"/>
            <!--<attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.javafx.main.Main" />-->
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.poterion.texovac.application.Main" />
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Version" value="2.2" />
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
            <!--<attribute name="JavaFX-Application-Class" value="com.poterion.texovac.application.Main" />-->
            <attribute name="Created-By" value="JavaFX Packager" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <zip destfile="${dist.dir}/${app.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${bundle-dist.dir}/${tmp.file}" excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA , META-INF/maven/**,META-INF/*.txt" />
    </zip>

    <delete file="${bundle-dist.dir}/${tmp.file}" />
    <delete dir="${bundle-dist.dir}"/>
</target>
```