# How to work with JMeter and Junit

Tags: jmeter, junit4

I am very new to JMeter

I am trying to use Junit Request sampler in JMeter.In my project we have a class called `PayloadProcessorTest.java`. from these class methods i am calling some other class methods.It has lot of dependencies

How can i create jar file for `PayloadProcessorTest.java` with dependencies

I saw many examples for JMeter with Junit Request sampler. But, those all examples are independent classes

Can any one please help me

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of creating a .jar file:

1. Using [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/2897748)
2. Using [Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1821912/2897748)
3. Using [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm)
4. .jar files are basically [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) archives so you can just compile your `PayloadProcessorTest.java` and put resulting `PayloadProcessorTest.class` into /lib/junit/test.jar file keeping package structure. After restart JMeter will pick up the class. Don't forget to add any 3rd-party jars used in PayloadProcessorTest (if any) to JMeter classpath. For more information check out [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the dependencies with Maven you can run
`mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies`, which will create a folder inside your target folder called 'dependency' filled with the dependencies. To speed this up you can add the command as External Tool in Eclipse using Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations.

Or if you want to use Eclipse you can choose File > Export > Java > Runnable JAR file and select the option 'Copy required libraries into a sub folder next to the generated JAR'. However to do this you will need to add a main class, and run it once as a Java Application before trying to export. The Main class can be empty or not.

```
package test;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Really, it depends what packaging capabilities you have.

You need to compile your classes in one or more jars, and then put them in the `%JMETER_HOME%/lib/ext` folder.

Or use `maven` to do it all for you.