# Recommended way of placing dependent jars in ContentNavigator

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

we have some dependent/common jars of the plugin which we are currently placing in .lib of ContentNavigator application and referring the same in build.xml of ContentNavigator. while we placed the jars in local and  tried to give the local path in build.xml it didn't worked out.Can anyone suggest what is the recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I've applied the following approaches:

1. [Embed/extract all the content(.class files) of the dependency-jars within the navigator plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821803/creating-a-bundle-jar-with-ant). While the upside is that you have a nice bundle containing all your dependency-classes, it might cause some problems with signed jar's. Or on files that are duplicate amongst your dependencies.
2. Make use of the ["Shared Library"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html) concept. You basically "attach" jar's to the classloader of your server/JVM, Application(ear) or module(war). In your case you would probably attach the shared-library to the navigator.ear, allowing all plugins to access the dependencies you register as a sharedlibrary. One huge downside is (in my experience) that you need to reboot websphere every time you update one of the library-jars.
3. A third option is to move the functionality out of your ICN Plugin, and let another EAR/EJB do the work (and reference to it from the plugin using a jndi lookup).

I personally prefer option 3 because it's the cleanest way to bundle your functionality&dependencies in an EAR. But option 2 will be a good call when libraries are truely common and won't be updated often.

*p.s. In your question you mention the build aspect of your software as well (e.g. "how to correctly reference the dependencies"). You might want to look into the concepts of "dependency management" (using Ant, IVY is a good choice, but i would suggest moving to Maven, or Gradle)*